# javascript module pattern return object reference?

Tags: javascript

my understanding is that objects are passed around by reference..
I've implemented the module patters as below.

```
var myModule = (function(){
    var obj = {};

    return {
        obj: obj,
        updateObj: function(newObj) {
            obj = newObj;
        }
    }

}())

myModule.obj;   //  {}
myModule.updateObj({foo:'bar'});
myModule.obj;   //  still {}  :(
```

Where am I going wrong?  Isn't myModule.obj a reference to the internal obj var?

EDIT:  ended up going with this:

```
var myModule = (function(){

    var public = {
        obj: {},
        updateObj: function(newObj) {
            public.obj = newObj;
        }
    }

    return public;

}())
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but from a quick look, your parentheses may be off. Shouldn't it be `(function() { ... })()` ?

Comment: There is a syntax error in there...somewhere `Unexpected token }`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes, `obj = newObj,` here comma should be `;`. _Ignoring syntax errors_

Comment: thanks @Tushar and SpencerWieczorek  typo fixed

Comment: @duxfox--  Nope, that the immediately invoking function pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong?

You're assigning a new reference to the `obj` **variable**, but that's not what your `console` code is looking at. It's looking at the reference in the `obj` **property** on the object you're returning.

> Isn't `myModule.obj` a reference to the internal `obj` var?

No. This:

```
return {
    obj: obj
    // ...
}
```

*copies* the object reference from the variable to the property, after which there is no link between the variable and the property.

After you've created `myModule`, before your callto `updateObj`, here's what you have in memory (with some irrelevant details omitted):

```
 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
 |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                     |
 +−>| execution context |                                     |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                     |
    | obj: Ref11235     |−−−−−+                               |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |                               |
                              |   +−−−−−−−−+                  |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−>| object |                  |
    | variable "myModule" |   |   +−−−−−−−−+                  |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                               |
    | obj: Ref11235       |−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
    | updateObj: Ref88452 |−−−−−−>|  function             |   |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
                                  | environment: Ref71423 |−−−+
                                  | [[code]               |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Ref11235 is just a plaeholder for the value of the object reference to that object. (Similarly Ref88452 is the object reference for the function, and Ref71423 is the object reference to the behind-the-scenes "EnvironmentRecord" object the `updateObj` function has a reference to so it can update that environment's `obj` variable.)

After your call to `updateObj`, you've changed the reference in the `obj` property of `myModule`, but that doesn't change the reference in the `obj` variable:

```
 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
 |                                +−−−−−−−−+                  |
 |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−>| object |                  |
 +−>| execution context |     |   +−−−−−−−−+                  |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |                               |
    | obj: Ref11235     |−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+         |   object   |              |
                              +−−>+−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |   | foo: "bar" |              |
    | variable "myModule" |   |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                               |
    | obj: Ref65243       |−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
    | updateObj: Ref88452 |−−−−−−>|  function             |   |
    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
                                  | environment: Ref71123 |−−−+
                                  | [[code]               |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

The only change is in `myModule.obj`'s value, which now refers to a new object.

---

If you change `updateObj` to update the *property* instead:

```
updateObj: function(newObj) {
    this.obj = newObj;
}
```

...then you'll see the result you expect. (At which point it would probably make sense to do away with the `obj` variable entirely.)

Comment: Vote + 1. For those diagrams. How did you create those?

Comment: @Tushar: Text editor. There's a secret to lining up the `−` and `+` though. ;-)

Comment: I'm a bit conflicted..   Awesome internals explanation and fix via using `this`..    @ivan-schmidt's answer wins in the succinctness category

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `obj` inside the `updateObj` does not refer to the `obj` variable that is defined inside the module. To refer to the same `obj` as in the `myModule`, use `this` context.

```
this.obj = newObj;
```

```js
var myModule = (function () {
    var obj = {};

    return {
        obj: obj,
        updateObj: function (newObj) {
            this.obj = newObj;
        }
    };
}());

console.log(myModule.obj);
myModule.updateObj({
    foo: 'bar'
});
console.log(myModule.obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't myModule.obj a reference to the internal obj var?

No, it isn't.

`var obj = {};` creates an object and assigns a reference to it as the value of `obj`.

`obj: obj` copies the value of `obj` (i.e. the reference) to the `obj` property of the other object.

`obj = newObj` overwrites the value of `obj` with a reference to the new object. This does not touch the `obj` property so it is still a reference to the first object.

Comment: That's what I thought may be going on...  `obj = newObj` is overwriting/replacing

Answer (score 1):

This one is similar to code below:

```
var a = {}, b=a;
a = {some:1};
alert(b.some);
```

That won't work, cause in line `a={some:1}` you are losing your link to b.

Hope it'll make sense!

Answer (score 0):

There are an objects in memory and there are adresses of this objects. Your variable `obj` contains address to object. When you assign `obj` variable to `obj` property you assign address. Then you overwrite address in `obj` variable to another object, but in `obj` property address is still the same.